# Icacls - Change permission invalid parameter

Tags: cmd.exe, file-permissions, icacls

When I enter:

```
icacls %SYSTEMROOT%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts "/E /G %USERNAME%:W"
```

It says invalid parameter `/E`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such parameters in `icacls` named `/E` or `/G`. Read `icacls /?`.

Correct command will be:

```
icacls %SYSTEMROOT%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts /grant "%username%:W"
```